# Download Button for IE - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have been using some Javascript code for another thread on here (I can not find the link but will add as soon as I can.)

Aim: To create a button that will allow the user to download when they click it rather than right click and save as. In Chrome/Firefox you can use the 'Download' attribute but IE does not support this and the client uses IE.

The code picks up the image (it can see the size when I run through the code) but does not download it and the error comes up as "0" which is not to helpful. I  am not a Javascript specialist so any help is appreciated. I am running this on my desktop at this time.

Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                function DownloadImage(imageURL) {
                    var oImage = document.getElementById(imageURL);
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                    if (typeof canvas.getContext == "undefined" || !canvas.getContext) {
                        alert("browser does not support this action, sorry");
                        return false;
                    }

                    try {
                        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        var width = oImage.width;
                        var height = oImage.height;
                        canvas.width = width;
                        canvas.height = height;
                        canvas.style.width = width + "px";
                        canvas.style.height = height + "px";
                        context.drawImage(oImage, 0, 0, width, height);
                        var rawImageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");
                        rawImageData = rawImageData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
                        document.location.href = rawImageData;
                        document.body.removeChild(canvas);
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        document.body.removeChild(canvas);
                        alert("Sorry, can't download" & canvas);
                    }

                    return true;
                }

        window.onload = function () {
            var arrButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
            for (var i = 0; i < arrButtons.length; i++) {
                var oButton = arrButtons[i];
                var sRelatedImage = oButton.getAttribute("rel");
                if (sRelatedImage && sRelatedImage.length > 0) {
                    oButton.onclick = function () {
                        HandleRelatedImage(this, sRelatedImage);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        function HandleRelatedImage(oButton, sRelatedImage) {
            var oImage = document.getElementById(sRelatedImage);
            if (!oImage) {
                alert("related image '" + sRelatedImage + "' does not exist");
                return false;
            }

            return DownloadImage(sRelatedImage);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnDownload" rel="myimage" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <%--   <buttontype="btnDownload" rel="myimage">--%>
        <asp:Image ID="myimage" runat="server" src="test.jpg" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check out this article on Content-Disposition headers: http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way of achieving what you want is to do it server side by setting the headers of the returned page. (Possibly not appropriate if you require to do it in JS for some reason, but I did something similar a few years back and a bit of server side code made things a lot easier).

You seem to be using VB so try this link http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/how_to_force_a_file_to_download_in_aspnet.aspx